# Export to Excel Implementation

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

```
function fnshowAuditList() {
     if(auditListTable)
        auditListTable.fnDestroy();
     jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'auditListAction',
            data: '',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            jQuery("#auditreportsright #tab_4_1_0 tbody").empty();
            jQuery.each(obj, function (index, value) 
            {
                 jQuery("#auditreportsright #tab_4_1_0 tbody").append("<tr>"+
                   "<td>"+value.jobInstanceName+"</td>"+
                   "<td>"+value.jobName+"</td>"+
                   "<td>"+value.appName+"</td>"+
                   "<td>"+value.serverName+"</td>"+
                   "<td>"+value.serverURL+"</td>"+
                   "<td>"+value.startTime+"</td>"+
                   "<td>"+value.endTime+"</td>"+
                   "<td><span class='"+value.status+"'>"+value.status+"</span></td>"+
                   "<td>"+value.exception+"</td>"+
                 "</tr>");
            });

            auditListTable = jQuery('#tab_4_1_0').dataTable({
                 "bFilter": true,
                 "bDestroy": true,
                 "bRetrieve": true,
                 "aaSorting": []
             } );
         //  auditListTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'] ] );

         } //fucn                  
     });
}
```

The above javascript function gives an ajax call to a java class and gets the data in json and the same is populated in table.

I also want to populate this data in excel and want export to excel functionality.

Please suggest me how to achieve that in jquery. Or can that be handled in java itself.

Comment: plz have a look at ActiveXObjects in javascript.That may help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it in Java  -A java class that get data in json and this class export data in excel format. You may take a look at Apache POI.

http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can export a HTML table to Excel using pure JavaScript.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/y0jwhnco/1/

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var myFileName = 'MyFileName.xls';
a.download = myFileName;
a.setAttribute('href', uri + base64(format(template, ctx)));
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myFileName));
document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(a);
```